# Create works and update fails because of custom validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an online shop:

The problem here concerns two tables, product and size

**product has_many sizes**

**size belongs_to product**

The admin must provide the products attributes plus the nested sizes attributes (`:size_name` and `:quantity`) when he creates a product

In product model I have this "custom " validation:

```
validate :at_least_one_size

def at_least_one_size
  if self.sizes.empty?
    errors.add(:base, :require_size)
  end
end
```

Each time a product is sold, the corresponding size is decreased...

And when there is no size anymore, the product is out of stock...

Now if I want to re add some stock and update my product with new sizes I face my custom validation error...

As my product is out of size, it's like if it is not valid anymore and I can't even update it...

I was thinking of something like `optional true` on my custom method but is not correct...
What should I do ?

Comment: If you need validation only on creation, you can add the condition `validate :at_least_one_size, on: :create`

Comment: awsome ! many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind, I'll convert my comment to the answer, to not leave the question unanswered.

Since you need to validate record only on creation, you can use `on` option, it works for custom validations too

```
validate :at_least_one_size, on: :create
```